# Reading C structs from file in python

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, struct

I have very little experience with C, so I apologize in advance if something I say does not make sense.

I am working on a project in which my entire base of code is written in python 2.7.  I am at a point where I must read in data created by someone else who is using C.  Each data file  he has given me consists of a header struct, such as...

```
struct Header {
    int32_t x1;
    int32_t x2;
    .
    .
    .
};
```

This is then followed by an array of structs of identical format, each containing data for a single element in a simulation.

Is there a way to read this data in with python?  It seems like I need to use python's struct module, but I've read through the documentation and either I can't find what I need or don't understand how I should use it.

Thank you!

Comment: What did you try and what didn't work?  You're right that you want to use the `struct` module.

Comment: An alternative would be the `ctypes` module but this is even harder to understand (but more flexible)

Comment: You also need to consider endianess of the source and target...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at either the `struct` module `pack` & `unpack` functions or the `ctypes` module - either will sort you out which is better depends on several factors, `numpy` also includes functions for reading 'alien' data that can help..

Comment: I've used the struct module's unpack function before to read in data from a binary file, and I've just been trying to use it in a similar way to read in this data.  For example, to read in the first piece of data in the header I originally posted, I would just use unpack to read it in as a 4 byte integer.  This is giving me nonsensical values, however, which leads me to believe the data I'm reading is not the data I want. I'm assuming there is some formatting or byte padding in the way C structs are saved that I'm not taking into account. If so, where can I find out about this? Thanks!

Comment: Is the data from a windows or unix machine, are you running on the same - if the endian is different you will need set that in your unpack string, likewise padding.

Comment: The data was created on the same unix cluster that I am using to unpack it.

Comment: Then you would likely need native endian and packing. '@iiii' should be worth a try.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but shouldn't I only need '@i' for a 32 bit integer? I've been under the impression that the 'i' flag counted as 4 bytes. Regardless, this is still giving me nonsense back. I'll be able to talk to the guy who created the data later today, so I can check if there's something I'm missing with the format of his structs. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you know what should be in one of your sample files it worth calculating the exact size of the file that you expect and comparing it to the actual size, i.e. if your sample is expected to be a header of 20 bytes and have 100 32 byte records then it should be exactly 3220 bytes long.  E.g. If it is 4 bytes more then suspect things like magic numbers at the file start, if it is 200 bytes more  then suspect padding between records, if it is twice what you expect then either the int type is wrong or the fields are padded, etc,